# Problem with Reading a specific table from SQL Server by mssql in javascript ('dbo.index')

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express, node-mssql

I have to read a table named `dbo.Index` from SQL Server in my node js express app but it fails and returns nothing.

Here's my code:

```
app.get('/getData',  (req, res, next) => {
    const config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: '12345',
        server: 'localhost',
        database: 'myDB'
    }
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)

    pool.connect(err => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        console.log('connected.')

        const request = new sql.Request(pool)
        request.query(`SELECT * FROM dbo.Index`, (error, recordSet) => {
            if (err) console.log(error)
            res.send(recordSet)
        })
    })

})
```

I've tested this code and it works well with **other tables** but with this specific name `dbo.Index`, it fails.

It's necessary for me to read it and I can't change the table name (have no permission).

I use **node-mssql** package in order to connect to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDEX` is a [Reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), so you will need to wrap it in square parentheses, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Index]
```

It's generally best to try and avoid using reserved words for table or column names as it easily leads to confusion, mistakes and bugs.